# How can I delete the second node in a linked list while the head is at the third node?

Tags: linked-list

How can I delete the second node in a linked list while the head is at the third node?

Comment: Is that a single linked list?

Comment: Its asked to me in an interview ? I told them its impossible. Is it right?

Comment: If it is a single linked list, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is doubly linked list, it is possible.

```
head->prev->prev->next = head;
head->prev = head->prev->prev;
```